# Na prática, o que é um teste de sistema e o que ele deve abranger?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, testes

Dentre os testes mais conhecidos entao os **testes de unidade** que testam cada classe do sistema de modo individual, os **testes de integração** que testam duas partes distintas do sistema, como um DAO e o banco de dados. Mas e o teste de sistema? O que ele é, como é feito e qual o seu objetivo?

É testar até mesmo a interface(view) do sistema?

Comment: Olha, eu conheço *Unit Tests*, *Acceptance Tests* e *Functional Tests*, além de testes e2e, mas não me recordo de ter ouvido esse termo **Teste de Sistema** antes. Pode me mostrar algum lugar onde viu isso?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos vi em livros, em alguns lugares estava descrito como teste de software.

Comment: Creio então que **Teste de Sistema** e/ou **Teste de Software** seja uma generalização que engloba todos os tipos de teste

Comment: @ThiagoSantos creio que não, segundo o livro que li (TDD: Test e Design no Mundo Real): "Um teste de sistema é aquele que é idêntico ao executado pelo usuário da aplicação. Se sua aplicação é uma aplicação web, esse teste deve subir o browser, clicar em links, submeter formulários etc.". Mas depois pesquisando em outras fontes encontro algo meio diferente que isso. Por isso resolvi perguntar.

Comment: Isso que tu descreveu soa muito como um teste funcional, que faz os exames que tu mencionaste.

Answer (score 2):

O **teste de sistema**, pode ser considerado a "terceira fase" dos teste, sendo a primeira **teste de unidade ou unitário**, que testa as menores unidades do sistema, procurando por erros de lógica e implementação em cada módulo, separadamente. A segunda seria o **teste de integração**, que tem por objetivo detectar falhas na interação entre as unidades, geralmente os tipos de falhas encontradas são de envio e recebimento de dados. Lembrando que a integração com outros sistemas não fazem parte dessa fase.

O **teste de sistema** tem por objetivo testar o sistema por completo. É comum chamar este teste de caixa preta, pois o sistema é testado com tudo ligado: batch jobs, banco de dados, serviços web, etc.. Este teste coloca a prova o sistema por completo.

Na prática eles são executados em condições similares aquelas que o usuário irá utilizar. Esse teste verifica se os componentes são compatíveis, se eles interagem corretamente, se transferem os dados certos no momento certo,etc.

Para responder a sua pergunta "É testar até mesmo a interface(view) do sistema?", veja essa [imagem (slide 20)](http://www.nti.ufpb.br/~caroline/curso/Aula01-Curso%20de%20Testes%20de%20Software%20-%20NTI.pdf), ela mostra um resumo dos testes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos ver, a resposta para sua pergunta é Sim. É nessa fase que é testada a interface do sistema.

Existem também os **teste de aceitação** e **teste de regressão**. O teste de aceitação tem por objetivo verificar a conformidade com os requisitos de negócio e usuário na última fase do ciclo de desenvolvimento, validando o produto para entrega. Eles são geralmente realizados por um grupo restrito de usuários finais do sistema. Já o teste de regressão é aplicado quando lança uma nova versão do software ou quando existe a necessidade de se executar um novo ciclo de teste durante o processo de desenvolvimento. Ele não é considerado um nível de teste, mas é uma estratégia importante para redução de efeitos colaterais.

Referências e links relacionados:

- [Testes de Software](https://testesw.wordpress.com/processo-de-testes/)
- [Fases de Testes de software](http://www.matera.com/br/2013/07/19/fases-de-testes-de-software/)
- [Fases de Testes](http://qualidade-de-software.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/fases-de-testes.html)
- [Teste de Software](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/9572/software/teste-de-software/?trace=1519021197&source=single)
- [Unidade, integração ou sistema? Qual teste fazer?](http://blog.caelum.com.br/unidade-integracao-ou-sistema-qual-teste-fazer/)

Answer (score -2):

Na prática vejo que o teste deve ser feito para todo o teste que se torna caro de ser feito manualmente.

Nenhum teste estará tão atualizado como um teste feito por uma pessoa e por isso, vejo que na prática, você deve criar testes buscando a estabilidade e escalabilidade do código, garantindo com que a solução está madura e não sofreu impactos no decorrer de novas implementações.

Criar testes sem que a solução implementada esteja madura muita das vezes faz com que o teste precise ser reescrito.

Pensando desta forma, não importa se o teste é por UI(tela a tela) ou por código, mas sim se ele é honeroso de se fazer manualmente ou se já é um caso de uso (soluçã) maduro o suficiente para viabilizar a escrita do teste, naquele momento.

Enfim, na prática, você deve balancear o esforço de implementar o teste automatizado (e suas alterações) com o esforço do teste manual.

Comment: Em que momento tu responde "o que é um teste de sistema"?

Answer (score -3):

Minha opinião é que sim, é testar a interface que do sistema, certificar que todos os recursos disponíveis para os usuários estejam funcionando antes de colocar o sistema em produção. Mas vai além disso, o momento do projeto e o contexto em que se aplica poderá exigir uma bateria de testes de regressão por exemplo, que envolve testar cada funcionalidade e garantir que regras específicas do negócio do cliente estão funcionando como se espera. O fato de testar se um botão está funcionando, se o sistema é responsível ou se roda em vários browsers pode não parecer tão importante quanto outros testes para quem possui conhecimentos técnicos, ou participa do projeto, no entanto para usuários finais do sistema ou por quem paga por ele pode agregar um valor muito grande, por isso se faz necessário os testes de interface de um sistema, assim como tantos outros.